# How to use multiple vpn clients with wireguard on windows?

Tags: windows, vpn, wireguard

I have multiple connections to the same vpn server. One connection is a wireguard with access to the Internet, the other is an openvpn connection with access only to the local network of the remote server. But when I connect to wireguard all other connections don't work. How to add other routes when connected to wireguard vpn? It seems that when wireguard connected, it blocks all other routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your WireGuard connection profile *does not* list `0.0.0.0/0` or `::/0` as its AllowedIPs, because this causes the Windows client to automatically activate the "Block untunnelled traffic (kill-switch)" feature – it inserts hidden firewall rules preventing packets from going through any other interface regardless of routes.

To avoid this, change the profile to:

```
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1, ::/1, 8000::/1
```

These prefixes still combine to 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 and have the same effect as a "default route", but it won't trigger the block rules as long as it doesn't literally say "0.0.0.0/0" in the profile.

Disabling the "Block untunnelled traffic" checkbox will do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been to the settings many times but never saw this checkbox "Block untunnelled traffic".